# Keyboard does not work with Menu when use ngTemplateOutlet in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to navigate Menu options by using keyboard.
The problem is that i can't focus items via keyboard that are provided by ngTemplateOutlet.

Follow a problem Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvfzyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.html

Comment: The content inside `ng-content` will load only after `AfterContentInit` life cycle, It will be attached to the template after a while. So, some bevaiours mayn't be coming up. But in which scenario you need this?

Comment: It is required for more complex thing. I'm creating a context-menu based on menu from Angular Material. The options inside menu are coming from other components and some of them can by async, some of them have different views...

And because of variety, menu has been divided on ng-templates by using ngTemplateOutlet and ngSwitchCase

Comment: In this case, handle those async operations on component.ts file,  don't bother templates. Bind the menu items into mat-menu by using `ngFor`directive.